# Django, general version of prefetch_related()?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Of course, I don't mean to do what prefetch_related does already.

I'd like to mimic what it does.
What I'd like to do is the following.

I have a list of MyModel instances.
A user can either `follows` or `doesn't follow` each instance.

```
my_models = MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)

for my_model in my_models:
   my_model.is_following = Follow.objects.filter(user=user, target_id=my_model.id, target_content_type=MY_MODEL_CTYPE)
```

Here I have n+1 query problem, and I think I can borrow what `prefetch_related` does here. Description of `prefetch_related` says, it performs the query for all objects and when the related attribute is required, it gets from the pre-performed queryset.

That's exactly what I'm after, perform query for `is_following` for all objects that I'm interested in. and use the query instead of N individual query.

One additional aspect is that, I'd like to attach queryset rather than attach the actual value, so that I can defer evaluation until pagination.
If that's too ambiguous statement, I'd like to give the `my_models` queryset that has `is_following` information attached, to another function (DRF serializer for instance).

How does `prefetch_related` accomplish something like above?

Comment: What is the `target_id` field in the `Follow` model ? Is it a `ForeignKey` to `MyModel` ?

Comment: @Todor it is 'object_id' part of GFK. I've updated the query in the question to show that it's GFK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution where you can get only the `is_following` bit is possible with a subquery via `.extra`.

```
class MyModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_is_follwing(self, user):
        return self.extra(
            select = {'is_following': 'EXISTS( \
                SELECT `id` FROM `follow` \
                WHERE `follow`.`target_id` = `mymodel`.id \
                AND `follow`.`user_id` = %s)' % user.id
            }
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):

    objects = MyModelQuerySet.as_manager()
```

usage:

```
my_models = MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs).annotate_is_follwing(request.user)
```

#### Now another solution where you can get a whole list of `following` objects.

Because you have a `GFK` in the `Follow` class you need to manually create a `reverse` relation via [GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation). Something like:

```
class MyModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_user_following(self, user):
        return self.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'following', 
                queryset=Follow.objects.filter(user=user) \
                    .select_related('user'), 
                to_attr='following_user'
            )
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):

    following = GenericRelation(Follow,
        content_type_field='target_content_type',
        object_id_field='target_id'
        related_query_name='mymodels'
    )

    objects = MyModelQuerySet.as_manager()

    def get_first_following_object(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'following_user') and len(self.following_user) > 0:
            return self.following_user[0]
        return None
```

usage:

```
my_models = MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs).with_user_following(request.user)
```

Now you have access to `following_user` attribute - a list with all `follow` objects per `mymodel`, or you can use a method like `get_first_following_object`.

Comment: very illuminating. I've not used `GenericRelation` before. Are we using it to define the `reverse of GFK` here

Comment: oh you said so in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, and I doubt this is what prefetch_related does because I'm joining here.

I found there's way to select `extra` columns in your query.

```
        extra_select = """
        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM follow_follow
        WHERE follow_follow.target_object_id = myapp_mymodel.id AND
        follow_follow.target_content_type_id = %s AND
        follow_follow.user_id = %s)
        """

        qs = self.extra(
            select={'is_following': extra_select},
            select_params=[CONTENT_TYPE_ID, user.id]
        )
```

So you can do this with join.

`prefetch_related` way of doing it would be `separate queryset` and look it up in queryset for the attribute.